# Insert multiple rows from Jtable to sql database table

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, jdbc, jtable

I'm trying to insert rows data from JTable to table in sql database but on runtime facing error

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Transaction'.

***Here is the code***

```
try {

    int rows = table.getRowCount();

    //  con.setAutoCommit(false);
    String query = "Insert into Transaction(transaction_code, transaction_date, item_code, item_name, quantity, item_price, total) values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?) ;";
    PreparedStatement pst = con.prepareStatement(query);
    for (int row = 0; row < rows; row++) {
        int t_code = (int) table.getValueAt(row, 0);
        Timestamp t_date = (Timestamp) table.getValueAt(row, 1);
        int i_code = (int) table.getValueAt(row, 2);
        String i_name = (String) table.getValueAt(row, 3);
        int quantity = (int) table.getValueAt(row, 4);
        BigDecimal i_price = (BigDecimal) table.getValueAt(row, 5);
        BigDecimal total = (BigDecimal) table.getValueAt(row, 6);
        pst.setInt(1, t_code);
        pst.setTimestamp(2, t_date);
        pst.setInt(3, i_code);
        pst.setString(4, i_name);
        pst.setInt(5, quantity);
        pst.setBigDecimal(6, i_price);
        pst.setBigDecimal(7, total);

        pst.addBatch();
    }
    pst.executeBatch();
    pst.execute(query);
    //con.commit();
} catch (Exception e1) {
    e1.printStackTrace();

}
```

Comment: transaction is reserved word

Comment: The word "transaction" is a reserved word in most SQL database, you have to quote it, like `"Transaction"`...

Comment: wwhat DBMS you are using?

Comment: I am using microsoft sql server YCF_L but its working now as i changed the table name from Transaction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Transaction` is a [keyword](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keywords.html) in mysql an many other dbms. Do not use it as tablename or escape it with backticks